# How to get google-cloud-ops-agent logging to recognize special "severity" field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-ops-agent

I am running ZooKeeper on a google compute instance and trying to setup google-cloud-ops-agent to properly parse the logs.  I am most of the way there, but am having trouble getting it to recognize the `severity` field.

The docs state that `severity` is a special field that will get extracted from the `jsonPayload`, but I am not seeing that happening.

- [special fields documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent/configuration#special-fields)
- [logEntry documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogSeverity)

My `/etc/google-cloud-ops-agent/config.yaml`

```yaml
logging:
  receivers:
    zookeeper:
      type: files
      include_paths:
      - /zookeeper/logs/zookeeper.log
  processors:
    zookeeper:
      type: parse_regex
      field: message
      regex: '^(?<time>.{23}) \[(?<zknode>[^\]]+)] - (?<severity>\S+)\s+ \[(?<class>[^\]]+)] - (?<msg>.*)$'
      time_key: time
      time_format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%L"
  service:
    pipelines:
      zookeeper:
        receivers: [zookeeper]
        processors: [zookeeper]
```

evidence the parse_regex is working properly (but notice severity still exists in `jsonPayload`)

[image: sample Cloud Logging Output]

Comment: Any clues on the Zookeeper logs? What ops agent version are you also using?

Comment: No, I never got it to work.  I can't find the specific version I was using, I was following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/ops-agent/installation; it was not the 'legacy' or 'preview' versions (at time of this writing). Unfortunately this project got defunded, so I had to move on.  I appreciate the suggestions

Comment: I've ran into the same problem. I've got a support ticket open and I'll update with what I find.

Comment: A public ticket has been created for this issue, See [case](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202309453) for more details. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202309453

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by describing in processors:

```
    change_severity:
  type: modify_fields
  fields:
    severity:
      copy_from: jsonPayload.severity
```

and then to service -> pipelines:

```
      web_access:
    receivers:
      - web_access
    processors:
      - change_severity
```

Comment: This is not the recommended way to resolve the issue. This relies on an implementation detail of the logging sub-agent that is subject to change in the future. The destination field should be just `severity`, not `jsonPayload."logging.googleapis.com/severity"`.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing an unstructured log, the Ops Agent places all fields under `jsonPayload` *unless* the field has one of the special names from that table, as you've pointed out from the docs. However, in that table `severity` is the *destination* field, not the source. The correct source field is spelled `logging.googleapis.com/severity`.

Unfortunately the regex engine does not allow special characters in destination field names. If it did, you could simply write your regex as e.g. `regex: '^(?<time>.{23}) \[(?<zknode>[^\]]+)] - (?<logging.googleapis.com/severity>\S+)\s+ \[(?<class>[^\]]+)] - (?<msg>.*)$'` and the problem would be fixed.

Because you can't write that regex, you need an additional processor to lift the `jsonPayload.severity` field to the top-level `severity` field:

```yaml
logging:
  ...
  processors:
    move_severity:
      type: modify_fields
      fields:
        severity:
          move_from: jsonPayload.severity
  service:
    pipelines:
      ..
        processors:
          ..
          - move_severity
```

Additionally, `severity` only recognizes [specific inputs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogSeverity), e.g. a warning must be spelled as `WARNING` and not `WARN` or `W`. If you're collecting logs that spell the severity level differently, you can add a corresponding `map_values` section to the `move_severity` processor.